# ViewModel Inheritance for different actions with Twitter Bootstrap MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a ViewModel in MVC that allows me to switch between the display format and the edit format.

I can get the Controller to select the correct version of the ViewModel and all the properties for the inherited class and base class show in the debugger.

When the ViewModel is passed to the view, only the properties from the inherited class show up.

Can this approach work or should I create two seperate ViewModels?

**ViewModel:**

```
public partial class HouseholdViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int familyID { get; set; }
        public string entityName { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime attachmentDate { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class DisplayHouseholdViewModel : HouseholdViewModel
    {
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class CreateHouseholdViewModel : HouseholdViewModel
    {
        public string familyPhoneCode { get; set; }
        public string familyPhone { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller (snippet):**

```
public class HouseholdController : Controller
    {
        private WhatWorksEntities db = new WhatWorksEntities();

        //return viewmodel object
        private string displayView = "displayView";
        private string createView = "createView";

        public IEnumerable<object> GetModel(string view)
        {
            if (view == displayView)
            {
                var householdView = (from h in db.tHouseholds
                                     select new DisplayHouseholdViewModel
                                     {
                                         Id = h.householdID,
                                         familyID = h.familyID,
                                         entityName = h.tEntity.entityName,
                                         attachmentDate = h.attachmentDate,
                                         phone = h.familyPhoneCode + " " + h.familyPhone
                                     }).AsEnumerable();
                return (householdView);
            }
            else
            {
                var householdView = (from h in db.tHouseholds
                                     select new CreateHouseholdViewModel
                                     {
                                         Id = h.householdID,
                                         familyID = h.familyID,
                                         entityName = h.tEntity.entityName,
                                         attachmentDate = h.attachmentDate,
                                         familyPhoneCode = h.familyPhoneCode,
                                         familyPhone = h.familyPhone
                                     }).AsEnumerable();
                return (householdView);
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Household/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var householdView = GetModel(displayView).Cast<DisplayHouseholdViewModel>();

            return View(householdView);

        }
```

The view that is returned doesn't display the *phone* property:

[image: Index View]

---EDIT to show debugger with phone data---

**Debug view:**
[image: Debugger]

Comment: In your controller you set phone equal to h.familyCode + " " + h.familyPhone, if you put a breakpoint on it you are actually getting a value there?  Also can you post your code from View?

Comment: yes; post updated with debugger image

Comment: And in your view you have some code to render the phone number but it is not, and is also omitting the header?

Comment: The View code is the standard shared view code from the Twitter Bootsrap for MVC4 off NuGet. The column for the phone number is not being passed into the view at all, even though the data is collected for the viewmodel.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by standard view code from Twitter Bootstrap for MVC4 off NuGet.  If you created a view and then added another field to what you want to display you have to go into that view and add logic to display it.  How do you know it is not being passed into the view based off your snippet above it for sure is being passed - unless your view is not of the correct type or is not displaying that field

Comment: "Twitter Bootstrap for MVC4" is a package on NuGet that I'm using with my application. It contains a shared Create view that iterates through each property of the ViewModel and displays them. This works fine with non-inherited ViewModels but breaks with the inheritance. I've also noticed that the validation isn't working correctly either, so I think the simple answer is to use separate ViewModels rather than trying to switch between them...

Comment: I use Twitter Bootstrap in all of my projects but I have never seen this shared Create view so I guess you have something that I have never seen before : )

Answer (score 0):

In your view you need some logic to display the field -

```
@Html.LabelFor(l => l.Phone, "Phone")
@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Phone)
```

And at the top you need to make sure you are displaying the proper view model

```
@model YourNamespace.ViewModels.DisplayViewModel
```

If you are trying to change on the same view between two ViewModels you will need to create two separate partial views and toggle their display settings

Comment: It's actually the shared Index view for the code I've posted (sorry - I was working on the Create view whilst posting). The main reason for using the bootstrap is that the layouts iterate over the model and produce a standardised view/edit/create interface without having to manually code up each view. I will probably go with individual ViewModels.